# "Buffer2 is undefined" Error when using userbase-js with SvelteKit/Vite

Tags: node.js, vite, sveltekit

I get this error when importing `userbase-js` into a svelte file. First I tried to use it via a script tag but then I got the error `window is undefined` when declaring `let userbase = window.userbase`. I thought it would probably be better anyway to use it via the npm package. But how to I fix this error? 
Full error message:

```
Buffer2 is undefined

node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=4f8aa8dd:174:9
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QOVRSCHT.js?v=4f8aa8dd:11:50
node_modules/randombytes/browser.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=4f8aa8dd:230:19
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QOVRSCHT.js?v=4f8aa8dd:11:50
node_modules/diffie-hellman/lib/generatePrime.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=4f8aa8dd:3261:23
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QOVRSCHT.js?v=4f8aa8dd:11:50
node_modules/diffie-hellman/browser.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=4f8aa8dd:3543:25
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QOVRSCHT.js?v=4f8aa8dd:11:50
@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=4f8aa8dd:6155:37
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SvelteKit, first you would need to check whether your code is executed on the server by Svelte.

The `window` variable does not exist when on the server.
That's why every `window` usage must be put in the `onMount(...)` function, so that it is executed only when mounted onto the DOM, a time where the `window` variable exists.